# add item to data in react-arborist tree

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm using a library "react-arborist" for draggable tree but I don't know how can I add a tree element:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Tree, useSimpleTree } from "react-arborist";

export default function App() {
  const [data, controller] = useSimpleTree(initialData);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);

  return <Tree data={data} {...controller}></Tree>;
}
```

my function to add element:

```
function addtodo() {
        const newTodo = {
            id: nanoid(),
            name: "new file",
    ...
        };
        controller.onCreate((currentData) => [newTodo, ...currentData]);
    }
```

this creates a new element with empty name with the same ID.. to see the function [here](https://github.com/brimdata/react-arborist/blob/9e278965b0a622b32887e90d36dbf93b8ace561b/packages/react-arborist/src/hooks/use-simple-tree.ts#L19)

Comment: @karavanjo please if you have answers